# Can you subscribe to a flushall notification in REDIS

Tags: redis

I'm trying to subscribe to a `flushall` event notification but to no avail. I can succesfully subscribe to `DEL` keyevent but I want to get notified when a `flushall` is sent to my REDIS db.

I've read through https://redis.io/topics/notifications to try and make sure that my db is configured for all notifications (via `config set notify-keyspace-events KEA`).

I'm using `psubscribe '__keyevent@*__:del*'` for my `DEL` notification. I've tried all I can think of including `psubscribe '*flushall*'` to get the `flushall` to fire but can't get a hit.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: There's no such notification for flushall and flushdb. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278931/redis-keyspace-notifications-with-flushdb) is a similar question and a workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much. Not ideal, but at least there's a workaround that I can use.